# Looking for software for music recognition over a limited universe

Tags: macos, music-recognition

I'm trying to find a music recognizer for MacOS. The constraints are: Recognition over a quite limited (~1000) universe of songs that I provide and preprocess as needed; "listening" to music from the microphone; very high accuracy and speed of recognition; and usable programmatically, i.e. controlling recognition and receiving results from other code, not from a GUI.

Search gives me several possibilities: SongRec, AcousticID, maybe others, but each has potential pitfalls that I might not see for a long while. So I thought I'd ask here, in case anyone can tell me a good starting point. Thanks.